# Javascript: reduce function of an array of json objects don't return the addition of values

Tags: javascript

I've got this array of json objects with these data:

```
      let data = [
    {"id_player_team" : 1, "name" : "Jose", "t2p_conv": 3, "t3p_conv": 5},
    {"id_player_team" : 2, "name" : "Jesus", "t2p_conv": 2, "t3p_conv": 1},
    {"id_player_team" : 3, "name" : "Maria", "t2p_conv": 3, "t3p_conv": 0},
    {"id_player_team" : 4, "name" : "Irene", "t2p_conv": 4, "t3p_conv": 2},
    {"id_player_team" : 5, "name" : "Carmen", "t2p_conv": 1, "t3p_conv": 2},
  ];
```

I want to get the result of the addition of key "t2p_conv". To do this, I use reduce function of javascript, like this:

```
let sumt2p = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
     return acc + item.t2p_conv;
});
console.log("Result: " + sumt2p);
```

When I try to show the value of sumt2p I've got this result:

```
Result: [object Object]2341
```

How is possible that? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you're picking out a property like that, you need to supply the second argument to `reduce` to provide a seed value for `acc` parameter:

```
    let sumt2p = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
         return acc + item.t2p_conv;
    }, 0);
// −−^^^
```

If you don't supply the seed, the first call to your callback uses the first two entries in the array. Since you're using `+` on an object (the first object in `acc`), it gets converted to a string. :-)

---

This is one of the many reasons that `reduce` is usually [more complicated than necessary](https://twitter.com/bterlson/status/1099010861065068544). Here, for instance, a simple loop, perhaps with destructuring, does the job:

```
let sumt2p = 0;
for (const {t2p_conv} of data) {
     sumt2p += t2p_conv;
}
```